# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabIndicatorColor'

Tags: android, tabs

I know there're a few similiar questions but I haven't found correct answer. I try to use tabs in my app. I've created styles-21 file which looks like this :

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

However when I try to build project I'm getting an error :

```
Error:(20, 25) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabIndicatorColor'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':Baseline:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Programowanie\sdk1\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I try to use different sdk, changed target version in appcompat properties file but still got the same error. My gradle looks like this :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':zxing-2.3.0:android')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    }*/
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did either of my suggestions work for you or did you find a different way?

Comment: I have used one of tutorials that you recommended and it works so thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect by changing the color of the title of the tab or have an indicator bar. Basically you need to add a selector that will change the color. Look at this for a good example: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

This is another example of a really good material design tab layout with an indicator bar: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/